# How to fetch images from the Firestore in offline mode

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have uploaded the image to the Firebase storage and saved the URL in the Firestore DB. I want to fetch that image and display it in the UI **even when the device is offline.**

I did some research but could not find a correct and direct answer. Could anyone help with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you expect the image to come from when the device is not connected to the internet?

Comment: I think the OP wanted to ask when the application is opened without internet it should show the images which it has already downloaded earlier. In that case you should cache those images btw which framework are you using to build the application? flutter / native android, ios ?

Comment: The scenario is that the user can add a receipt(image) to the firestore storage from the add page and view it on the view page. Both actions have to be done offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in this [github thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2627), `firebase storage` doesn’t support uploading files offline.

> Firestore and Firebase Storage are very different under the hood. Firestore is a structured datastore that is meant to store small chunks of interpreted data, where Firebase Storage is a blob storage-based system designed to support much larger files. While offline support for Firebase Storage is certainly an often requested feature, the implementation would likely look very different from the implementation that we use in Firestore and hence these implementations cannot be shared.
>
> Despite the popularity of this request, offline support for Firebase Storage is currently not a feature that is being worked on. We will take your input into consideration as we prioritize future work items. Thank you!

You can try the workaround mentioned in the same [github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2627#issuecomment-1012126155).

> implement a fallback, which uploads the image to   `Firestore` too, when offline. The first request to this image could then upload it to the `storage` and replace it with the reference, or you could set up a triggered `cloud function` to handle this.

But you access data from firestore offline mode.

> Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

For more details you can check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)